# N-Genius payment gateway Access Token on laravel and on postman gives Bad Request 400 ERROR

Tags: php, laravel

when i am trying to get token according to this documentation:
[getting access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbwU4.png)
when running this code on laravel project:

```
$apikey = "[your-api-key]";     // enter your API key here
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-gateway.sandbox.ngenius-payments.com/identity/auth/access-token"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "accept: application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json",
    "authorization: Basic ".$apikey,
    "content-type: application/vnd.ni-identity.v1+json"
   )); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  "{\"realmName\":\"ni\"}"); 
$output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); 
$access_token = $output->access_token;
```

it returns:

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Bad token request",
            "localizedMessage": "Bad token request",
            "errorCode": "badTokenRequest",
            "domain": "identity"
        }
    ]
}
```

and on postman:
[image]

the documentation is very poor and I need your help!
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbwU4.png): https://docs.ngenius-payments.com/reference/request-an-access-token-paypage#code-example-php--curl

Comment: any test API key to test?

Comment: @OMiShah No it was a real api key from service account.

Comment: I am asking for any test api keys so that we can check.

Comment: i dont think so, they provide test to test cards only.

Comment: Try creating a new api key and try. Else contact their support.

Comment: also done, and contacted them no response till now